# Directive does not see elements in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, timeout, element, angular-directive

I am having troubles to understand why my directive does not seem to work properly. Here's the quick overview of the problem:

I load the HTML using Ajax that contains Angular elements. The Ajax response is $compiled, so those elements works, but the problem is that I have to timeout it with 0 seconds.

```
<div my-directive button="bar">
    <button id="foo">Foo</button>
</div>
<button id="bar">Hi!</button>
```

and the js:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var foo = element.find('button');
        var bar = $(attrs.button);
    }
};
});
```

The above foo-bar elemenets will not be found until I surround them with setTimeout(..., 0);

Can someone tell me if there's a better approach to get access to them without having setTimeout?

Comment: is Ajax call an external call for AngularJS or you use $http.* ?

Comment: I used $http service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is the right way to achieve this but you should use $timeout.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function() {
           var foo = element.find('button');
           var bar = $(attrs.button);
        },0);
    }
};
});
```

It's just changing priority of execution code in javascript.

Comment: I see, if that is the proper approach, then I am okay with that :) thanks man.

Comment: It may help you.. http://lorenzmerdian.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-handle-dom-updates-in-angularjs.html